# trouble while writing a var for function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, programming-languages

I trying to to a function like this, but it couldn't work. could you have a look on this ^^

```
var test:testMc;

addMonster(test,testMc);

public function addMonster($mon:MovieClip,$monMc:MovieClip)
{$mon= new $monMc(stage, enemy);
}
```

Line 3    -      1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.

Line 6 -    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method $monMc.

How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: Instantiate the testMc class.

Comment: May I know... What are u trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future you should have posted more code and told us which lines those errors were on, because in this case we can't see where you declared testMc or the line numbers. Fortunately in this case it doesn't matter because I can see the problem at a glance.

The second parameter in addMonster() is typed MovieClip when in fact the object is a Class. That is the cause of both error messages. Your code should be something like:

```
public function addMonster($mon:MovieClip,$monMc:Class)
```

---

Incidentally, I'm very curious why you would write code like this. I guess this could be a small snippet from some sort of factory class, but at a glance this looks like a pretty goofy way to instantiate an object.

Comment: Opsss, so that's why ^^ I'm just new to use variable inside a function, thus I was caught in this basic mistake T_T. And Yup, these codes are just a small part in my addMonster function, since I have to do a lot of things when the monsters were released T_T thank you for your help!!

Comment: I would have written this so that it returns the instantiated object, rather than passing in a reference variable. So the function call would be "var test:testMc = addMonster(testMc);". I didn't even realize AS3 supports reference variables because I've never seen that (bad) practice anywhere other than C code.